# OR operator in Cypress.io

Tags: node.js, cypress

I am unable to build condition on which the test to be successful if page results are "No matching records found" OR "No data available".
Is there an "OR" operator in Cypress? (none in the documentation)

I have tried to use nodejs to do the logic, but cypress throw error on the first condition.

```
        if (cy.get('.v-table__overflow > table > tbody > tr > td').contains('No matching records found') || cy.get('.v-table__overflow > table > tbody > tr > td').contains('No data available')) {
          cy.log('Record does not exist as Expected!');
        } else {
          cy.pause();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Don't know what your HTML looks like but does it make sense that you've written a selector for every cell in the table and checking it matches a static value?

Comment: It is the same cell, it can be either "No matching records found" or "Record does not exist as Expected!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Cypress code is totally incorrect. Please I suggest you to check how [assertations](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Existence) work in Cypress.

UPDATE:
You can achieve it doing something like this:

```js
cy.get('.v-table__overflow > table > tbody > tr > td').should('have.not.text', 'No matching records found').and('have.not.text', 'No data available');
```

or

```js
cy.get('.v-table__overflow > table > tbody > tr > td').invoke('text').then((text) => {
  expect(text).not.equal('No matching records found')
  expect(text).not.equal('No data available')

})
```

Also, I see that you are checking that specific messages are not shown. Instead, consider to check that some elements are shown. This way test will be more clear.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, can you please elaborate on that? I already got through the assertations documentation, but haven't found a way to confirm the test if you have OR case. Means you can have for example "TEXT1" OR "SOMETHING2" on the same page as a result.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `satisfy` for this

```
cy.get('.v-table__overflow > table > tbody > tr > td')
    .should('satisfy', (elements) => {
        const text = elements[0].innerText;
        return text === 'No matching records found' || text === 'No data available';
    });
```